# Group By en Laravel con Mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy realizando la siguiente consulta sobre mi gestor de base de datos. la cual funciona perfectamente mostrando la info esperada:

```
select 
       ca.id,
       a.name, 
       a.description, 
       t.name as type_activity, 
       c.name as category,
       uca.created_at

from activities as a
join category_activities as ca on a.id = ca.activity_id
join user_category_activity as uca on uca.category_activity_id = ca.id
join type_activity as t on a.type_activity_id = t.id
join categories as c on c.id = ca.category_id
where uca.state_id = 2 and uca.user_id = 3 and c.id = 65
group by id
order by uca.created_at
```

Pero al pasar la consulta a laravel, de la siguiente manera:

```
$activities = DB::table('activities as a')
            ->join('category_activities as ca','a.id','=','ca.activity_id')
            ->join('user_category_activity as uca','uca.category_activity_id','=','ca.id')
            ->join('type_activity as t', 'a.type_activity_id','=','t.id')
            ->join('categories as c','c.id','=','ca.category_id')
            ->select('ca.id', 
                    'a.name', 
                    'a.description', 
                    't.name as type_activity', 
                    'c.name as category',
                    'uca.created_at')
            ->where('uca.user_id', 3) 
            ->where('c.id', 65) 
            ->where('uca.state_id',2)
            ->groupBy('ca.id')
            ->orderBy('uca.created_at','DESC')
```

Me aparece un error "Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'ennlacebox.ca.id' isn't in GROUP B", el cual deja de aparecer en cuanto añado todos los campos en el group by, así:

```
->groupBy('a.id','ca.id','a.name','a.description','t.name','c.name','uca.created_at')
```

Pero en ese momento el GroupBy deja de ser inservible pues necesito que la información se me agrupe por el campo 'ca.id'

ayuda por favor, gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! la primer consulta no anda.. muestra simplemente cualquier cosa.. lee la pregunta enlazada...

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias BetaM y gbianchi. Me queda claro el tema de agrupamiento. Ya logré ajustar la consulta en laravel, me quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
$activities = DB::table('activities as a')
            ->join('category_activities as ca','a.id','=','ca.activity_id')
            ->join('user_category_activity as uca','uca.category_activity_id','=','ca.id')
            ->join('type_activity as t', 'a.type_activity_id','=','t.id')
            ->join('categories as c','c.id','=','ca.category_id')    
            ->select(DB::raw(' ca.id,
            a.name, 
            a.description, 
            t.name as type_activity, 
            c.name as category,
            max(uca.created_at) as created_at'))  
            ->where('uca.user_id', $u->user_id) 
            ->where('c.id',$u->category_id) 
            ->where('uca.state_id',2)            
            ->groupBy('ca.id','a.name','a.description','t.name','c.name')
            ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
            
            ->get();
```

Comment: El tema no tiene que ver con Laravel, esto es a nivel de MySQL, Laravel solo te informa el error que MySQL le dio producto de tu consulta